# I can't delete a custom album with its photo using PHPhotoLibrary

Tags: swift

I'm having hard time trying to figure out how to delete the custom albums made by my app along with its photos. NOTE: I can delete albums but not along with its photos.

THE CODE I'M BASING ON FROM STACKOVERFLOW: It works, but it deletes all the photos from the camera roll.

```
func deleteAllPhotos() {
    let library = PHPhotoLibrary.shared()
    library.performChanges({
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        let allPhotos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)
        PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(allPhotos)
    }) { (success, error) in
        // Handle success & errors
    }
}
```

MY MODIFIED CODE BASED ON THE ABOVE CODE:

```
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", albumName)

let assetCollections = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)
let album: PHAssetCollection = assetCollections.firstObject!
let allPhotos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)

PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
    guard let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: (album)) else { return }
    let fastEnumeration = NSArray(array: [allPhotos])
            albumChangeRequest.removeAssets(fastEnumeration)
        }, completionHandler: { success, error in
        if success {
            print("removed")
        } else {
            print("not removed")
        }
    })
```

> ERROR: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported predicate in fetch options: title == "albumName"

Comment: Apparently no one has the answer for this, guess I’m gonna figure that out by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use `in` with the `album` for `fetchAssets`:

```
let allPhotos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: album!, options: nil)
PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(allPhotos)
```